# Undefined reference to apache::thrift::server::TThreadedServer::TThreadedServer

Tags: c++, boost, thrift

I have client-server program which uses Thrift.

However, it throws out following errors:

> undefined reference to apache::thrift::server::TThreadedServer::TThreadedServer(boost::shared_ptr const&, boost::shared_ptr const&, boost::shared_ptr const&, boost::shared_ptr const&, boost::shared_ptr const&)

I used following steps to install Thrift:

```
git cone https://github.com/apache/thrift.git

cd thrift
./bootstrap.sh

./configure --with-boost=/usr/local

cd test/cpp; ln -s . .libs; cd ../..

make -j4

make install

ldconfig
```

[step to link the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qX60P.png)

Comment: So waht steps did you take to link thrift with your program?

Comment: [step to link the program][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qX60P.png

Comment: So I'll ask the question again, what changes did you make to your makefile to tell the linker to link with the thrift library? It's not enough to install the library you have to also change your build procedures to link with the library.

Comment: hello, it is difficult to point out the changes of makefile, as this is a huge project with many linked makefiles.    The same process works for ubuntu 16.04, but failed on Debian 8.11 with the error show in the PNG file.